# Smarty: how to evaluate string as a variable

Tags: php, smarty

Variable assigned in my template is {$testVariable_123}, where 123 is auto generated and is also assigned to template as {$autoValue}

So in my template I want to get value of above variable.

```
{assign var="anotherValue" value="testVariable_"|cat:$autoValue}
```

So if I print {$anotherValue} instead of value I get string 'testVariable_123'

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable whose value is `{$testVariable_123}`
Then you can call `{eval}` on it.

The problem is, I couldn't find a way to do this in a good manner.
Everything that looks reasonably good doesn't work and the options that work are ugly.

Maybe you'd consider some changes in your application design?

Here's what I managed to get working:

```
# file.php:

  $smarty->assign("autoValue", 123);
  $smarty->assign("testVariable_123", "foo");

  //Option 1
  $smarty->assign("anotherValue", "{\$testVariable_123}");
  //Option 2
  $smarty->assign("rb", '}'); // Hack to get the right bracket } withou Smarty parsing it.
  //Option 3
  $smarty->assign("mask", '{$testVariable_%s}'); // pass the full string_format "mask" directly from PHP

# file.tpl

1) Uses the $anotherValue from PHP:
Plain: {$anotherValue}
Evaled: {eval var=$anotherValue}

2) Build the string on Smarty itself:
{assign var="yetAnotherValue" value=$autoValue|string_format:"{\$testVariable_%s$rb"}
Plain: {$yetAnotherValue}
Evaled: {eval var=$yetAnotherValue}

3) Build the string using the mask from php:
{assign var="enoughOfValue" value=$autoValue|string_format:$mask}
Plain: {$enoughOfValue}
Evaled: {eval var=$enoughOfValue}
```

Mostly, the problem is that Smarty won't ignore a closing bracket } or a $variable even if it's in the middle of a string. Escaping with \ doesn't work neither.

If you try:

```
{assign var="yetAnotherValue" value="{\$testVariable_$autoValue}"}
```

it will ignore the "} at the end and consider the Smarty statement as:

```
{assign var="yetAnotherValue" value="{\$testVariable_$autoValue}
```

and it will evaluate the $testVariable even tho it was supposed to be escaped.
So we will end up with `{\123` as the value :(

Everything I tried ended up stumbling on that issue.
If you find a better way, please, make sure you share it here :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it's complicated.. :(
I changed my logic in my application.

Comment: Cool! I'm happy to help. At least it was fun to figure out an (ugly) solution. :)

Comment: Just commenting to make you aware of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29312144/2459228), as you seem to be interested in a solution not stumbling on the issue you described :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking for is this:

```
{assign var="anotherValue" value='{$testVariable_'|cat:$autoValue|cat:'}'}
{eval var=$anotherValue}
```

You can also get the value without having to assign a new variable:

```
{eval var='{$testVariable_'|cat:$autoValue|cat:'}'}
```

The trick is to use single quotes, so that Smarty does not automatically try to evaluate things that look like variables immediately.

Comment: Still looks ugly overall but definitely seems better than the ones I suggested :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
{assign var="myVar" value="{\$testVariable"|cat:$autoValue|cat:$smarty.rdelim}
{eval var=$myVar}
```

Worked for me.